# Regex capture group 2 to capture what does not match capture group 1

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am wanting to capture Owner or Builder in group 1, otherwise any text up until hyphen and/or space followed by a digit is encountered in group 2, then any digit til end of line in group 3 from the following text:-

```
PRD Hervey Bay 07 2525 1919
RG Sprake &amp; Co Maryborough 4141 2424
Owner Robert - 0429 966 391
Owner Maureen - 07 8888 4444 - 0422000 111
Owner Wayne - 0430 555 666
Builder Scott - 0444 555 777
```

The expression I am currently using:-

```
/(Owner|Builder)([^-]+)-|\s+(\d.*)/gm
```

Does not match 'PRD Hervey Bay' and 'RG Sprake & Co Maryborough' in group 2.

Any help appreciated!

Trent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to get the results you want:

```
/^(Owner |Builder )?(.*?)(?=-| \d)[- ]+(.*)$/m
```

It looks for (optionally) the string `Owner` or `Builder`; followed by some minimal number of characters until a `-` or a space followed by a digit; followed by some number of `-` or space, then characters until end of line. To use in PHP:

```
$text = <<<EOD
PRD Hervey Bay 07 2525 1919
RG Sprake &amp; Co Maryborough 4141 2424
Owner Robert - 0429 966 391
Owner Maureen - 07 8888 4444 - 0422000 111
Owner Wayne - 0430 555 666
Builder Scott - 0444 555 777
EOD;
preg_match_all('/^(Owner |Builder )?(.*?)(?=-| \d)[- ]+(.*)$/m', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array (
    [0] => PRD Hervey Bay 07 2525 1919
    [1] => RG Sprake &amp; Co Maryborough 4141 2424
    [2] => Owner Robert - 0429 966 391
    [3] => Owner Maureen - 07 8888 4444 - 0422000 111
    [4] => Owner Wayne - 0430 555 666
    [5] => Builder Scott - 0444 555 777 
    )
  [1] => Array (
    [0] => 
    [1] =>
    [2] => Owner
    [3] => Owner
    [4] => Owner
    [5] => Builder
    )
  [2] => Array (
    [0] => PRD Hervey Bay
    [1] => RG Sprake &amp; Co Maryborough
    [2] => Robert
    [3] => Maureen
    [4] => Wayne
    [5] => Scott
    )
  [3] => Array (
    [0] => 07 2525 1919
    [1] => 4141 2424
    [2] => 0429 966 391
    [3] => 07 8888 4444 - 0422000 111
    [4] => 0430 555 666
    [5] => 0444 555 777
    )
  )
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/MEhn3)

Note that this does leave some spaces and `-` in the last group, you can most easily remove them (if desired) by using `array_walk`:

```
array_walk($matches[3], function (&$v) { $v = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $v); });
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/5tI5b)

Comment: Thanks Nick. Appreciate the verbosity when just a regex was needed. As for the hyphen in the last group; I will actually be exploding on that character to get all the alternative numbers for named entity in capture group 2. Cheers.